# NLS Curve Fit Singular matrix error

Tags: r, curve-fitting, nls

I need help fitting nls and finding initial estimates that would not lead to singular matrix. I will greatly appreciate any help.

```
via_data$Concentration <- c(0.197, 0.398, 0.792, 1.575,
                            3.154, 6.270, 12.625, 25.277,
                            25.110, 49.945, 74.680)
via_data$Viability <- c(100, 94.62, 96.21, 87.53, 
                        80,  62.22,  39.11, 
                        30.80,  30, 22, 2.56) 
x <- via_data$Concentration
y <- via_data$Viability
fit <- nls(y ~((1/(1+Epsup/x)^Bup)*(1/(1+Epsdn/x)^Bdn)), start=list(Epsup=0, Bup=1, Epsdn=10, Bdn=-5), trace=T)

Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

thanks,
Krina

Comment: Your formula is identical to `y ~ 1/(1+Epsup/x)^(Bup+Bdn)` Because of that you can only estimate `Bup+Bdn`. Also identical: `y ~ (1+Epsup/x)^(-Bup-Bdn)`

Comment: Ths is not the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34201377/r-and-nls-singular-gradient-matrix-at-initial-parameter.  In that question the problem was overparameterization.  This problem is not, in general, overparameterized but only if `Epsup = Epsdn` or if  any of the parameters are close to zero and as well there is the problem that we must be sure that `1+Epsup/x` and `1+Epsdn/x` remain positive.  Thus if we can find starting values sufficiently good to stay away from such bad areas it can be solved..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below `st` is your starting values except we have used `Epsup=1` to avoid degeneracy at 0. `fo` is the formula.  To prevent raising negative numbers to a power we have replaced `Epsup` with `sqrt(Epsup^2)` and similarly for `Epsdn` -- this adds the assumption that `Epsup` and `Espdn` cannot be negative.  (This would be the same as using `abs(Epsup)`; however, nlxb does not have `abs` in its derivative table.) Next use `nls2` to generate values on a grid between the boundaries `st/10` and `10*st`.  `nls2` will generate these and return an `"nls"` object with the best one found.  Now use that as the starting values for `nlxb` of the nlmrt package.  It handles difficult problems bettter than `nls`.  `nlxb` does not return an `"nls"` object (although the package does have `wrapnls` which runs `nlxb` followed by `nls` but then we don't get the direct output from `nlxb`) so feed that through `nls2` again to create an `"nls"` object allowing us to use the `fitted` method.  We plot the resulting fit.

```
library(nlmrt)
library(nls2)

st <- c(Epsup=1, Bup=1, Epsdn=10, Bdn=-5)
fo <- y ~ (1/(1+sqrt(Epsup^2)/x)^Bup)*(1/(1+sqrt(Epsdn^2)/x)^Bdn)

fit.nls2 <- nls2(fo, start = data.frame(rbind(st/10, 10*st)), alg = "brute")
fit.nlxb <- nlxb(fo, data = data.frame(x, y), start = coef(fit.nls2))
```

giving the following:

```
> fit.nlxb
nlmrt class object: x 
residual sumsquares =  171.2  on  11 observations
    after  19    Jacobian and  25 function evaluations
  name            coeff          SE       tstat      pval      gradient    JSingval   
Epsup            10.7464         10.95     0.9814     0.3591   6.855e-05        1584  
Bup              1.15049        0.5928      1.941    0.09345    0.001839       120.2  
Epsdn            642.754         908.5     0.7075     0.5021  -1.298e-06       1.406  
Bdn             -1.13885        0.6315     -1.804     0.1143    0.004964    0.005443
```

and plotting to visually assess the fit:

```
fit.nlxb.nls <- nls2(fo, start = coef(fit.nlxb))
plot(y ~ x)
lines(fitted(fit.nlxb.nls) ~ x)
```

[image: screenshot]

**Note:** We used this input:

```
via_data <- data.frame(Concentration = c(0.197, 0.398, 0.792, 1.575,
     3.154, 6.270, 12.625, 25.277, 25.110, 49.945, 74.680),
Viability = c(100, 94.62, 96.21, 87.53, 80,  62.22,  39.11, 
                        30.80,  30, 22, 2.56))
x <- via_data$Concentration
y <- via_data$Viability
```

Comment: very helpful. Thanks